# Retain the last value of the loop

Tags: php

I have a loop that I want to retain the last value of a variable.

```
$count = 20;
$data_list = 6;
$ceil = ceil($count / 6);
for($y=0; $y < $ceil; $y++){
 $new_x = 0;
 for($x=$new_x ; $count<20; $x++){  
  foreach($success_arr as $key => val){
   if($x < $data_list){
    echo $val[$x];
    $new_x = $x;
    $data_list = $data_list + $x;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Is it possible to retain the value of new it in the next loop?
And the `$data_list` variable?

Comment: Will you explain briefly your need ?

Comment: maybe you can push $data_list to array string and reuse for next loop

Comment: Could you elaborate what you want to do in the line `for($x=$new_x ; $count<20; $x++)`. Here you are initialising `$x` But comparing using `$count`. In the initial part you have declared `$count = 20;` So the for loop will never get executed as the test condition will always return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Initialise `$new_x = 0;` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is quite unclear. If you mean to say that your variable `$new_x` should retain its value in the second `for` loop and the variable `$data_list` should retain after all the loops, Then the answer is they are retained. You can check this out by adding `echo $data_list;` after all the loops. It would print out the value `6`.

Now if your question is why is `echo $val[$x];` not working? Then I would say you have a problem in the `for` loop `for($x=$new_x ; $count<20; $x++)`. Here you are initialising `$x` but in the comparison of the loop you are using variable `$count` which has been initialised to `20` so the comparison `$count < 20` always evaluates to `false`. So this loop will never execute.